# Name resolution of tables with similar name while querying

Tags: oracle

I have 3 schemas in Oracle:

1. Two schemas lets say A and B have a table with same name :-say Table X
2. I have granted select rights to schema C on Table X from both tables.
3. Now if I write select * from X in schema C.

Which table will it use to select from X schema A or schema B ???

Comment: Or... neither, if you haven't done anything else. What happens when you try? Have you created any synonyms, or changed C's current schema in the session you're querying in?

Comment: Why don't you use explicit schema names in you SELECT, like A.X?

Comment: If you're in this kind of situation where its possible for confusion then just qualify the table names with the schema name that you are interested in..

Comment: yes but the code was already written as select * from X; in prod and it automatically took one of the schemas.It was only then I realised that it took the wrong schema.I will be changing the code and using it as select * from A.X or select from B.X as needed.But I posted it to simply know wether someone knew how Oracle picks it up............................................Basically it was architecture related question and not coding related.

Comment: Then you probably already have a synonym (private to C, or public) pointing to one of them; or possibly your current schema is being changed automatically.

Comment: I checked the synonymns...there were none to be found In USER_SYNONYMS............................................................................................or possibly your current schema is being changed automatically.(is that possible because I have never seen anything like that before)

Answer (score 1):

> Which table will it use to select from X schema A or schema B ???

Neither.

In the situation where you have just granted `SELECT` permissions to `C` then:

```
select * from X
```

will result in

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist.
```

You would need to qualify the query with the schema:

```
select * from A.X
```

or

```
select * from B.X
```

or you would need to create a synonym:

```
CREATE SYNONYM X FOR B.X;
```

then `select * from X` will use table `X` in the `B` schema.

Comment: I also thought so but here is an interesting fact.When I queried from the table

Comment: select * from X

Comment: It gave me select * from A.X